# Yandex.maps xml.parsers.errors

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse XML with Python, i using package yandex-maps https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yandex-maps, but not getting very far.

```
>>> from yandex_maps import api
>>> api_key = 'my_api_key'
>>> pos = api.geocode(api_key, u'Санкт-Петербург, Бумажная 4')
```

I getting error:

```
File "./1.py", line 6, in <module>
    pos = api.geocode(api_key, u'Санкт-Петербург,Бумажная 4')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandex_maps/api.py", line 49, in geocode
    return _get_coords(xml)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yandex_maps/api.py", line 66, in _get_coords
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1928, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 6, column 2
```

Comment: This example does not work any value(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, Yandex returns you 301 to https protocol, when you use this lib (api.py line 13: "GEOCODE_URL = 'http://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?'")
So, just find another lib, or rewrite URL :)

Also, you can apply this fix: https://bitbucket.org/kmike/yandex-maps/pull-requests/2/fix-301-from-http-to-https/diff